# HTML5 getUserMedia() for multiple microphones

Tags: html, audio, microphone, getusermedia

Is there any way that we can use `getUserMedia()` of HTML5 to take audio input from a specific microphone, and not just the default one?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the getSources API which is as of yet not that well supported I'm afraid. I think that [Chrome has a version of it](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1571) available hidden behind a configuration flag, but other than that there's nothing that you can do other than wait.

Not the answer you wanted to hear I know, sorry.